# laptop not booting to ubuntu 13.04 after installing windows 8

Tags: 13.04, windows-8, easybcd

I have a laptop(hp pavillion n-series)which has got inbuilt ubuntu and now I installed windows 8 from the CD.
I can no longer boot through ubuntu but can only open windows 8. I would like to access both the operating systems through my laptop. I have tried using EasyBCD2.1.2 but i cannot find ubuntu under it.
plz help me out asap

Answer (score 2):

Just burn a Boot-Repair-Disk (http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) and run boot-repair. That should fix it.

You can read about boot-repair here: http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: How can he run `boot-repair`? Is it a command line tool or a GUI app? Is it installed by default on the *Live* edition?

Comment: Oh, I indeed wrote livedvd instead of repair disc. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem when I installed windows after Ubuntu. Had to delete the partition through windows, where Ubuntu is located, and reinstall Ubuntu. Now after restart I am able to select which version of Ubuntu to load and whether I want to load Windows.